# Unable to find superadmin.p12 file after successful EJBCA deployment with JBOSS EAP and ant

Tags: ant, jboss, ejbca

I'm attempting to deploy and install EJBCA on CentOS 7.6 using JBOSS EAP 6.0.4 and ant. My database is MariaDB. After executing the commands ant deploy and ant install, the log files indicate a successful build. I can access the EJBCA admin page via http://localhost:8080/ejbca/, but I noticed that the superadmin.p12 file is missing from my file directory.
I've checked the log files for any information related to the download of the superadmin.p12 file, but there doesn't seem to be any relevant entries. I've also tried restarting the JBOSS service, but the issue persists.
Any insights or suggestions on why the superadmin.p12 file is not being generated or where it might be located would be greatly appreciated.
Environment:
CentOS 7.6
JBOSS EAP 6.0.4
MariaDB

Steps taken:
Executed ant deploy and ant install commands.
Verified successful build in the log files.
Accessed the EJBCA admin page at http://localhost:8080/ejbca/.
Unable to locate the superadmin.p12 file in the file directory.
Expected behavior: The superadmin.p12 file should be generated during the EJBCA deployment and accessible in the file directory.
Additional information:
No error messages or warnings observed during the deployment process.
Attempted restarting the JBOSS service, but the issue persists.
Thank you for any assistance or guidance you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a version that is many many years old. I really recommend using a later version as there are known CVEs against old versions.

Apart from that, "ant install" will in the output state when and where it generates superadmin.p12, so look through that output carefully. The default location (unless you specified something else) is current_directory/p12/superadmin.p12

Comment: Thank you very much, I later used a higher version of ejbca and have successfully built